# for N(θ,1), Score Test is equivalent to UMPU test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study

Could you help me prove that For N(θ,1) density, Rao's Score Test is equivalent to UMPU test?

Comment: Please read the [tag wiki info](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) for the `self-study` tag. With that in mind, what have you done so far, and where do your difficulties lie?

Comment: What is the Fisher Information for the distribution in question? What is then Rao's test? What is the corresponding rejection rule?